# How to convert ISO-2022-CN text to UTF-8 in Java?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a Java application that needs to convert a string encoded in ISO-2022-CN to UTF-8. However, when I try to do this using the following code:

```
new String("Text".getBytes("ISO-2022-CN"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I get a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

After some research, I learned that ISO-2022-CN does not support encoding. However, I still need to convert the ISO-2022-CN string to UTF-8. How can I achieve this in Java?

I tried using the following code:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String iso2022cn = "Text";

    // Decode ISO-2022-CN to Unicode
    CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("ISO-2022-CN").newDecoder();
    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    ByteBuffer iso2022cnBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(iso2022cn.getBytes("ISO-2022-CN"));
    CharBuffer unicodeChars = decoder.decode(iso2022cnBytes);

    // Encode Unicode to UTF-8
    CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();
    encoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    ByteBuffer utf8Bytes = encoder.encode(unicodeChars);

    String utf8String = new String(utf8Bytes.array(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(utf8String);
  }
}
```

But this code also does not work for me.

Can anyone suggest a solution or provide an alternative approach to convert ISO-2022-CN text to UTF-8 in Java?

Comment: Read this about text   XIV. "Charset Language character conversion" and the source code link                       https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gjHmdC-BW0Q2vXiQYmp1rzPU497sybNy/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Sorry, can not make anything of your document. Could you provide an example? @SamuelMarchant

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/intl/supported-encodings.html#GUID-F8900850-51B5-4B8B-88C0-6186DF1C16B5

Comment: I had to extract it in my mobile, generally, it requires taking the output string and passing it over first pass. reEncodechars() method as in the comments at the top of the code. Unfortunately it's a reasonably simple version as its settings in the encoder are to skip over errors without an exception where possible.

Comment: ISO-2022-CN-GB works for me. Pity your string is just English 'ascii' though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method:

```
public static String iso2022cn2utf8(String src) {
    StringBuilder dest = new StringBuilder();
    boolean isConvert = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < src.length(); i++) {
        char c = src.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
            case 0x1b:
                i += 3;
                break;
            case 0x0e:
                ++i;
                isConvert = true;
                break;
            case 0x0f:
                ++i;
                isConvert = false;
                break;
            default:
                dest.append(isConvert ? (char) (c | 0x80) : c);
                break;
        }
    }

    return dest.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The String in your question is only being "tag marked" as UTF-8.

**See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html for details of character set encoding names and alias names easier to write than the name with _ or- symbol.**
Java only uses the - dash symbol in a character set name.
If you do not use an intermediate web charset to convert through, on the first parse use the character set to convert to , then the same again.

The below code was written for web server use, hence errors and warnings are locked off and proceeded over except standard api exceptions.
A bad parse with strange characters usually means the character came from a file or machine that operated in another charset.

```
    /*
java.nio.charset.Charset defchar = java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset();
String charsetInputName = defchar.name(); // get default OS system underlying base charset code page
//  "UTF_8";  "GB18030"  //java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(); // "GB2312";  ///  "UTF_16";  // "UTF_8";  "GB18030"
FOLLOWING is middle hop transfer reencode from ("GB18030") PRC Chinese simplified carrying an English subset to a (GB2312) Web Cinese simplified with English subset
THEN from the middle hop (GB2312) web charset to a standard English charset (UTF_8)
String charsetFrom = "GB2312"; 
String charsetNameto = java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(); //"GB2312"; US_ASCII   UTF_8
String charout = reEncodechars(java.util.Locale.ENGLISH,headerOrigin,"GB18030","GB2312");
charout = reEncodechars(java.util.Locale.ENGLISH,charout,charsetFrom,charsetNameto);
     */
    protected synchronized java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder setCharsetDecoder(String Iname){
        return (java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Iname)).newDecoder();
    }//enmeth

    
    
    
    protected synchronized java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder setCharsetEncoder(String Outname){
        return (java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Outname)).newEncoder();
    }//enmeth

    
    
    
    protected synchronized java.nio.CharBuffer getCharInBuffer(java.util.Locale locum, String headerOrigin, String charsetInputName)throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException, java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException{
        headerOrigin = (String) String.format(locum, "%s", headerOrigin);    // locale SVC served output control (is some help)  
        java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder ches = setCharsetDecoder(charsetInputName);
        ches.onMalformedInput(java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);  // IGNORE cannot do much inside a server
        ches.onUnmappableCharacter(java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
        return (java.nio.CharBuffer) ches.decode(((java.nio.ByteBuffer) java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(headerOrigin.getBytes(charsetInputName))));
    }//enmeth

    
    
    
    protected synchronized String inChars(java.util.Locale locum, String headerOrigin, String charsetInputName, String charsetnameto){
        String output = "";  //reEncodechars() "+arrayReady;
        try {
            java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder chunda = setCharsetEncoder(charsetnameto);
            chunda.onMalformedInput(java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
            chunda.onUnmappableCharacter(java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
            output = new String(((byte[]) ((java.nio.ByteBuffer) chunda.encode(((java.nio.CharBuffer) getCharInBuffer(locum, headerOrigin, charsetInputName)))).array()), charsetnameto);
            output = (String) String.format(locum, "%s", output);  // java.util.Locale SVC served output control (is some help)
        } catch (java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException unsuppode){
            unsuppode.printStackTrace();
        }
//
        return ((String) output);
    }//enmeth

    
    
    
// WARNING must have the charsets encodings installed available
protected synchronized String doEncodechars(java.util.Locale locum, String headerOrigin, String charsetInputName, String charsetnameto){
String retrieve = "";
String retrieve2 = "";
int lenorig = headerOrigin.length();
String sti = "";
for (int xz = 0; xz < lenorig; xz++){
sti = headerOrigin.substring(xz, (xz + 1));
retrieve += inChars(locum, sti, charsetInputName, charsetnameto);
}//enfr
try{
byte[] retr2 = retrieve.getBytes(charsetnameto);
retrieve2 = new String(retr2, ((java.nio.charset.Charset) java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(charsetnameto)));
} catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}
return ((String) String.format(locum, "%s", retrieve2));
}//enmeth


public synchronized String reEncodechars(java.util.Locale locum, String headerOrigin, String charsetInputName, String charsetnameto){
return (String)doEncodechars(locum, headerOrigin, charsetInputName, charsetnameto);
}//enmeth
```